# Two-term recurrence relation

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, recurrences, orthogonal-polynomials

We consider the following system of recurrence relations for $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $\vert \lambda \vert=1$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$

$$a_{n+1} = \lambda a_{n-1}+ \lambda^* a_n + \lambda^* n b_n $$
$$b_{n+1} = \lambda^* b_{n-1}+ \lambda b_n -  \lambda n a_n. $$

Here, $\lambda^*$ is the complex conjugate of $\lambda.$

I am interested in non-zero initial conditions under which $a_n,b_n$ tend to zero for $n \rightarrow \pm \infty.$

Observation: If there is a limit $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n \rightarrow b$, then indeed by the last term in each row, it has to be zero and $a_n =b_n=o(n)$

Comment: As $|\lambda|=1$ doesn't $\lambda^*=\lambda^{-1}$?

Comment: @AntoineLabelle thanks, is implemented now.

Comment: Do you have reasons to believe that such initial conditions exist?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I do, this comes from the matching conditions of coefficients in an ODE and numerically that ODE has a solution (for certain choices of $\lambda$ at least.) In particular, when $\lambda$ is the third root of unity.

Comment: @KungYao : I think it could be helpful for some MO users to see the details of what you mentioned in your latter comment.

Comment: The first equation can be solved for $b_n$, then that value can be substituted into the second equation. This gives a recurrence involving only $\{a_n\}$ with coefficients rational in $n$. I assume there is a theory about such recurrences.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: In the context of the corresponding ODEs (cf. my answer), this would be equivalent to transforming the system of two first-order ODEs to a single second-order ODE by substitution as pointed out by Alexey.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the initial conditions $a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1$ and that $n\to +\infty$.

Let $A(x):=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n$ and $B(x):=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n$. Then the recurrence relations become:
$$\begin{cases}
A(x) - a_1x - a_0 = \lambda x^2 A(x) + \lambda^* x (A(x)-a_0) + \lambda^* x^2 B'(x), \\
B(x) - b_1x - b_0 = \lambda^* x^2 B(x) + \lambda x (B(x)-b_0) - \lambda x^2 A'(x).
\end{cases}$$
That is, we have a system of 2 linear first-order ODE:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} A'(x)\\ B'(x)\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\lambda^* x^{-2}+x^{-1}+\lambda^{*2}\\ 
\lambda x^{-2} - x^{-1} - \lambda^2 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix} A(x)\\ B(x)\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix} \lambda^*(b_0x^{-2} + (b_1-\lambda b_0)x^{-1})\\
-\lambda(a_0x^{-2} + (a_1-\lambda^*a_0)x^{-1})\end{bmatrix},
$$
which may be analyzed with the standard methods.

Comment: so what are these standard methods?

Comment: @PritamBemis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev well, I am convinced you will not be able to write down any explicit solution fo that ODE. In fact, at the moment, it seems you just reformulated the question in a more complicated way.

Comment: @KungYao: I did not try, and so I cannot comment on feasibility of getting explicit solution at the moment. However, we don't need the solution per se, but only asymptotic of its coefficients. Also, this formulation may be "more complicated" (although it's a matter of taste) but it captures all the coefficients at once and shows explicitly the dependence on the initial conditions, which was somewhat hidden in your original formulation.

Comment: @PritamBemis This system of ODE can be replaced by one ODE of second order on $A(x)$ or $B(x)$.